# Using Cyberduck to SFTP to t2.micro EC2 instance Fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, sftp, cyberduck

I am trying to SFTP using Cyberduck to my t2.micro instance with EC2. I am repeatedly getting auhtentication failed. I am following all the steps as provided: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14971851/how-do-i-connect-to-my-ec2-instance-using-cyberduck-with-privileges) and [here](http://www.brianhoshi.com/blog/how-to-ftp-into-your-ec2-instance-with-cyberduck/).

I have successfully ssh'ed from terminal with the same .pem file.

However, from Cyberduck:
[image]

it fails:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To test your situation, I did the following:

- Went to the EC2 management console
- Created a **new keypair** and saved the key to disk
- **Launched** a new EC2 `t2.micro` instance, selecting the keypair I had saved and "Allow SSH traffic from 0.0.0.0/0"
- To test the EC2 instance, I **used SSH to connect to the instance**, specifying the keypair (I had to `chmod 600 key.pem` first`) -- the logon was successful
- Downloaded and installed Cyberduck (I'm on a Mac)
- **Configured Cyberduck**:

[image: Cyberduck configuration]

- Opened the connection -- it was **successful**.

Hopefully the above steps will help you figure out what is going wrong on your attempts.

Theoretically, if you can SSH into an instance then you can also use SFTP with it, since they connect in exactly the same way.

Comment: This is interesting. I am doing the same steps but cannot connect. I've tried with both the Public IPv4 address and the Public IPv4 DNS, both don't work. chmod 600 file.pem as well. I'm not sure if I'm doing somehting wrong or its a Mac vs Windows thing.